# getting the value of dropdown list from one page to another in c#

Tags: c#

```
if ()
{   
   HTML.Append("<tr class=\"odd\"><td valign=\"top\">" + "Technical: " + "<select> <option value=\"[Empty]\">[Empty]</option> <option value=\"Decline\">Decline</option> <option value=\"Follow-up\">Follow</option> <option value=\"Pursue\">Pursue</option> <option value=\"Watch\">Watch</option></select>" + "</td></tr>");  
}
```

Here Technical: is a dropdown in which if i select and submit the value must visibe another aspx page...help me on this regard

Comment: That code won't even compile. You don't have a condition for your if statement, so let's start there.

Comment: Consider the Condition has passed!

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET, it sounds like you might want to look into the Session object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session object or querystring to pass parameters.

```
Session["KEY"] = valuetobepassed;
```

and you can read it like

```
var valuepassed = Session["Key"] as typeof valuetobepassed
```

or you can append the value in the querystring and read from it in the next page

Comment: Just be aware that opening multiple tabs in your browser can conflict with state info saved in the `Session` object.